# How to change the colour of the WildMenu background?

Tags: vim, colors, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

I want to change the colour of the WildMenu background but I don't know which highlight group I need to specify.

`WildMenu` is the highlighted state of whichever item you have selected, not the background. I've checked the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#highlight-groups), but can't find the correct highlight group.

Does anyone know which one it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific highlight group for the background of the wildmenu. Instead, Vim simply uses `StatusLine`.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight groups specify both foreground and background colors. The colors used by the GUI and by color terminals are specified separately. To change the background color used by WildMenu in the GUI to red, for example, use

```
:hi WildMenu guibg=red
```

Comment: No, the background only changes for the selected WildMenu item, not the whole bar :(

Comment: Semantics. The term "background" in Vim refers to the background color of the character cells associated with the highlight group. Some other term is used to refer to the non-selected parts of menus. So I responded to what you said and romani responded to what you meant.